# Which user created a view on Snowflake

Tags: view, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there any way to get the user (not the role) that created a view?
I tried desc, show, grants on view but couldn't get the specific user

Answer (score 0):

The [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html)* table-functions have a USER_NAME column, and you can filter on the QUERY_TEXT to find the view's CREATE-statement.

This should work unless the views were created with a variable.  For example: `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW IDENTIIER($MY_VAR)...` where `MY_VAR` is a variable containing the name of the view.

---

UPDATE

INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY table-functions return results for the past 7 days.  Also see the [ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html#label-account-usage-views) table functions, which return results for the past 365 days, with a 45 minute lag.

---

UPDATE 2

You can also use conventions such as:

- Give each user their own schema, composed from their name or initials
- Ask users to put their name or initials in the view COMMENT
- Or ask users to prefix or suffix their views with their initials

If the views are created with a script or a stored procedure, then you can automate the above.

Lastly, while it's not a best practice, you can in fact create a separate role for each user.  This however creates a lot of administrative overhead, especially as you scale, and is not recommended.